# Using a DDE Server with Qt

Tags: qt, dde

I've searched high and low for a class that'll allow me to connect to a DDE server. Whilst I'm aware that DDE is dated and better methods exist, they don't for what I want to connect to.

I found [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20140811042756/http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.general/91) which apparently works in QT 3, and unfortunately I lack the knowledge of differences to update it to QT 4.

Does anybody have an updated version, the time to update or another solution?

Answer (score 1):

I know this ancient but to whoever gets here you need to make a small change to that code:

```
void DDEComm::ddeDisconnect()
{
 DdeDisconnect(hConv);
 DdeUninitialize(pidInst);
 connStatus = false;
}
```

should become

```
void DDEComm::ddeDisconnect()
{
 DdeDisconnect(hConv);
 DdeUninitialize(pidInst);
 connStatus = false;
 pidInst = 0;
}
```